# Is there a way to get a tab-local variable for a tabpage that is not currently activated

Tags: variables

I want to retrieve a `t:varible` for a different tabpage that is not the current tabpage. How can I do it **without switching to that tabpage**? I know its `tabpagenr`.

How about window local variables `w:` and buffer local ones `b:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just realize there are `getwinvar()`, `getbufvar()`, `gettabvar()` etc.